# How to best find what is writing to the Debug output in .net/c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a desktop c# .net app. Visual Studio 2019. 5 million lines of code.
One of them is spamming to the debug output window ( Debug.WriteLine() ).  Is there an easy way to find out (perhaps break on write) where the spam is happening?

I really don't want to have to go through and put in 500 breakpoints...

Comment: Presumably there is some common text that's part of the output. Why don't you just grep the sources for that text?

Comment: Assuming all debug message are the same (that would be crazy) you could use AOP and each time Debug.Write is called include the class/function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an empty `TraceListener` and put breakpoints on `Write()` and `WriteLine()`.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Trace.Listeners.Add(new MyTraceListener());
        Debug.WriteLine("testing");
    }

    class MyTraceListener : TraceListener
    {
        public override void Write(string message)
        {
            // breakpoint here
        }

        public override void WriteLine(string message)
        {
            // breakpoint here
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The suggestions given will certainly work. This is just another suggestion:

Add this using directive

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
```

Add the following method

```
    private void showDebug(string message, [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(message + " at " + lineNumber.ToString());
    }
```

Then replace all of "Debug.WriteLine" with "showDebug" (except in the added method)

This will definitely tell you where it is coming from.

Comment: I like this answer too.

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this I try to figure out which part of the message doesn't change and then search through the solution for that string.

Depending on you solution you may be able to put a conditional breakpoint in your base Log/Write method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) extension with filters for your app and the Debug.WriteLine method. In the captured flow you will see what code calls Debug.WriteLine.